# Why did Stack Overflow time out?

Tags: discussion, downtime

When I try to access http://stackoverflow.com, the page times out. I'd post this on Meta Stack Overflow, but it times out as well. All other sites seem to be working fine.

Using Chrome on OS X 10.10. Please fix!

---

Seems to be fixed now. So the question becomes: What happened?

Comment: no repro now...

Comment: And during that time, my profile page listed no other accounts. “You have no other accounts on the Stack Exchange network.”

Comment: @Anna lots of questions are getting closed as "Can't be reproduced" including completed bug reports, why reopening this specific one? Just curious, personally I'm also against this trend. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We had an issue causing the external IP addresses on the load balancers serving Stack Overflow to be in limbo. Normally, one of the two owns the IP address for Stack Overflow most people connect to and the other is a hot standby. However, during an upgrade of several modules tonight: keepalived, firewall, and HAProxy - this was not the case.

A cascading failure of the firewall to apply properly leading keepalived VRRP unable to communicate properly made both load balancers think neither had a peer. This results in a bit of swapping as they fight for ARP. When NY-LB06 "won" that fight, the second failure came into play: the firewall module did not finish updating on the first puppet run meaning the server was fully *ready* to serve traffic (from a Layer 7/HAProxy standpoint), but was not accepting TCP connections from anyone yet.

These issues have been fixed and we are running on the known-good load balancer (NY-LB05) with the upgraded one as a hot standby for testing this combination of new modules over the next few days.

It was not our intent to fail over to the new configuration at all tonight, but it happened. We knew there was a risk, as you should assume when changing firewalls, but wanted to mitigate it as much as possible. In this case, mitigation included doing the maintenance as off-peak traffic as we could.

We apologize for the trouble. As always, we'll write up a more detailed postmortem in the coming days so that others can learn and hopefully improve. You'll be able to find it on https://www.stackstatus.net/

A brief view of the swap because graphs are awesome:
[image]

Comment: Our work is done for the evening: http://theg2.net/gifs/Bender_Done.gif